# Show a function is not continuous at a point

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2 y^4}{x^4 + 6y^8}, & \text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0, & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

For the definition of differentiability, I have:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{||f(x+h, y+h) - f(x,y) - J(h)||}{||h||} = 0$$

So plugging in the function at $(0,0)$:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\left\|\frac{(0+h)^2 (0+h)^4}{(0+h)^4 + 6(0+h)^8} - f(0,0) - J(h)\right\|}{||h||} = 0$$

Because $f(0,0)$ is defined to be 0 at that point:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\left\|\frac{h^6}{h^4 + 6h^8} - J(h)\right\|}{||h||} = 0$$

I know $J(h)$ will be a $1 \times 2$ matrix, so I'm not sure how to deal with this situation here on out.

Comment: Are you trying to show that it is not *continuous* at 0, or are you trying to show that it is not *differentiable* at 0?

Comment: Well, I am trying to show it is not continuous, so that consequently is not differentiable. The question specifically states to prove it is not continuous first.

Comment: There are functions which are continuous but not differentiable. For example, the absolute value function is continuous but not differentiable at 0. To show that a function is not continuous, then, it is not enough to show that it is not differentiable.

Comment: The exact wording is: "show that $f(0,0)$ is not differentiable by showing $f(0,0)$ is not continuous." I thought the work I was doing would be showing that the function is not continuous, but upon consideration, I guess I'm nowhere near close to the solution. I will have to start over.

Comment: The problem then is to show that $f$ is not continuous. The point is that this fact then *implies* that $f$ is not differentiable, because every differentiable function *is* continuous.

Comment: To summarize:

Differentiable implies continuous, and so non-continuous implies non-differentiable.

Continuous does not imply differentiable, and so non-differentiable does not imply non-continuous.

Comment: In the definition of differentiability it should be $f(x + h_1, y + h_2)$ where $h = (h_1, h_2)$. Also $J$ is a linear function and for each $h \in \mathbb R^2$ $J(h)$ is a real number, not a $1 \times 2$ matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** (i) Approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $x=y^2$; (ii) Approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $x=y$.

Comment: Is it also valid to approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $x = 0$ or $y = 0$? Or is that not allowed because we are trying to approach $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, for (ii) you could approach along $x=0$ or $y=0$. The limits for each choice are $0$, just as with my choice $x=y$. We do need something like (i) to conclude that the limit does not exist.